# Merging two data sets in order to add default values for missing data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to merge two datasets in order to insert default rows for missing data. The use case is that I have a list of dates and attendance numbers for training sessions on those dates, but if I have no records at all for a training session then it's missing from the list.

In my sheet at the moment I have a two column set of dates and attendance numbers, and in another sheet, I have worked out all the Wednesdays and Fridays (training days) between the start and end dates of all the sessions we have data for.

Is there a way to merge the two datasets together so that the zero attendance for each session is the base set and then I merge in the rows for which I have data? I've tried using some of the query commands but if I specify two datasets using `{Sheet1!A1:A,Sheet2!B1:B}` I get array errors.

The attendance information is currently gathered with a query like this:

```
=QUERY({Records!A2:B}, "SELECT Col1, COUNT(Col2) WHERE (Col1 IS NOT NULL) 
 GROUP BY Col1 ORDER BY Col1 ASC LABEL Col1 'Session Date', COUNT(Col2) 'Skaters'")
```

where the Records sheets is just date and names.

If I update it to read from two datasets

```
=QUERY({Records!A2:B, Scratch!B2:B}, "SELECT Col1, COUNT(Col2) WHERE (Col1 IS NOT NULL) 
 GROUP BY Col1 ORDER BY Col1 ASC LABEL Col1 'Session Date', COUNT(Col2) 'Skaters'")
```

then I get a `#REF!` error of `Function ARRAY_ROW parameter 2 has mismatched row size. Expected: 982. Actual: 999.` Seems fair, as it's created a misaligned dataset, rather than merging based on the date column.

I'm probably treating the spreadsheet a bit too much like a database, and while I would be more comfortable dropping into the script editor to resolve this I'm trying to learn a few spreadsheet techniques.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Added some more info.

Comment: We could use FILTER, QUERY, OFFSET, ARRAY_CONSTRAIN and probably others functions to limit the number of rows returned by an open ended reference like `Sheet1!A1:A`. Have you tried any of this to avoid thee "mismatched row size" error?